# How could I store data from api inside a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have these data :

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":    
{"O":0.00019513,"H":0.00019527,"L":0.00019513,"C":0.00019527,"V":367.75179374,"T":"2019-04-29T21:00:00","BV":0.0717955325124862}, 
{"O":0.00019513,"H":0.00019583,"L":0.00019513,"C":0.00019583,"V":5389.26298513,"T":"2019-04-29T21:30:00","BV":1.0526250707404440},
{"O":0.00019474,"H":0.00019583,"L":0.00019474,"C":0.00019583,"V":2199.01385578,"T":"2019-04-29T22:00:00","BV":0.4306096361379076},
{"O":0.00019621,"H":0.00019621,"L":0.00019621,"C":0.00019621,"V":1747.38721102,"T":"2019-04-29T22:30:00","BV":0.3428548446742342},
{"O":0.00019627,"H":0.00019627,"L":0.00019452,"C":0.00019452,"V":452.75087850,"T":"2019-04-29T23:00:00","BV":0.0880756649231950}],"explanation":null}
```

And I would like to store these data in a dataframe. I tried this (the variable url contains the data above) :

```
reponse = urlopen(url)
data = json.load(reponse)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I would like to have 7 columns such as :

```
df['0'], df['H'], df['L'], df['C'], df['V'], df['T'], df['BV']
```

But I have no ideas to to this ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])` ?

Comment: I think that you should first select the "result" array from your json and then use it in your dataframe.

Comment: The JSON that you pasted is incorrect. Also, I think as @Rakesh and spassador suggested it should work.